# Datetime from params not saved correctly in the database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, timezone

I have the following situation . An user enters a date and time from rails's date and time select boxes and in the controller, method create, i have the following params:

```
"event"=>
  {"title"=>"tet",
   "start_date(1i)"=>"2013",
   "start_date(2i)"=>"4",
   "start_date(3i)"=>"26",
   "end_date(1i)"=>"2013",
   "end_date(2i)"=>"4",
   "end_date(3i)"=>"31",
   "start_time(1i)"=>"2013",
   "start_time(2i)"=>"4",
   "start_time(3i)"=>"26",
   "start_time(4i)"=>"10",
   "start_time(5i)"=>"05",
   "end_time(1i)"=>"2013",
   "end_time(2i)"=>"4",
   "end_time(3i)"=>"26",
   "end_time(4i)"=>"10",
   "end_time(5i)"=>"05"}
```

If i do

```
   @event = Event.new(params[:event])
```

the output is

```
=> #<Event id: nil, start_date: "2013-04-26", title: "tet", created_at: nil, updated_at: nil, owner_id: 0, owner_type: "", archived: false, end_date: "2013-05-01", start_time: "2013-04-26 10:05:00", end_time: "2013-04-26 10:05:00">
```

The end_date is not the same with the one in params

> Time.zone

returns

> => (GMT+02:00) Jerusalem

Why does this happen?

Answer (score 1):

There is no April 31, so it probably wraps to the next day after April 30 (May 1)

Comment: wow, it looks like you're right :D, so it's rails's fault :-s